# Is there a way to take an XmlNode and display its data in a datagrid view?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, web-services

I have spent about half a day searching for an answer to this question and am slowly becoming frustrated. I am working with a Web service that returns an XmlNode as its response. I would like to be able to take the XML data reference by the node and view it with a data grid view. Does any one know if this is possible?

I am using the following code:

```
         // submit command to webserver
         XmlNode response = SubmitToWebserv((XmlElement)IssueNode, state.Get);

        // create XML reader to read response
        XmlReader reader = new XmlNodeReader(response);

        // create a data table to hold response
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.ReadXmlSchema(reader);

        // read data into data table
        dt.ReadXml(reader);
```

It throws exception: DataTable does not support schema inference from Xml. The thing is, the schema is included in the XML referenced by response... So I am at a loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you try that using DataSet instead of DataTable. I don't know that it will work, but it makes sense that it would. The schema might have included more than one table.

OTOH, did the XmlNode include a schema at all?

---

I recommend you look at this in the debugger. In particular, watch to see which node the XmlReader is positioned on. I'm not 100% convinced it will advance as you want, from the wrapping element, to the schema, then to the data.

Also, is there an element wrapping the schema and data:

```
<node>
    <xs:schema/>
    <data/>
</node>
```

Or are the schema and data elements top-level nodes. This would be a fragment.

Comment: Yes, the schema is included in the XmlNode. This is why I am a little confused.

Comment: I used a DataSet instead and I was able to use display my data. Thank you. Now, to find a workaround for the vendor's poorly documented web service.

Thanks for the help StackOverflow!